# How to convert TensorVariable to numpy

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensor

I want to convert TensorVariable to numpy array and try:

```
feature_vector = keras_model.get_layer(blob_name).output.numpy()
```

But get the error.

> AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'numpy'

I also tried:

```
feature_vector = keras_model.get_layer(blob_name).output
init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(feature_vector.eval())
```

But get error

> theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: Input 0 of the graph (indices start
>   from 0), used to compute Shape(/input_1), was not provided and not
>   given a value. Use the Theano flag exception_verbosity='high', for
>   more information on this error.

Comment: Your error message states, that you used theano backend for keras. If you provide your imports, we can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Lau. Yes, I using theano as it turns out and fixed this error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643850/how-to-swich-theano-tensor-to-numpy-array)